# How to add border to card view with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-card

I find the way `Border(1.dp, Color.Black)` can not work with the border property of Card view, what's the best way to work around of it?

Answer (score 51):

You can use the `border` parameter to specify a [**`BorderStroke`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#borderstroke) to draw the border on top of the card:

```
Card(
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp,Color.Red),
        backgroundColor = Color.Yellow){

}
```

[image]

With **Material3** you can use:

```
Card(
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp,Color.Red),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Yellow)
)
```

Answer (score 30):

The border api of Card change to subtitle of Modifier, so it can add a border under below.

```
Card(modifier = Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Black)) {...}
```

Comment: If you are not looking for Some better answer then you should mark it accepted.

Comment: The problem with this answer is because the border is squared not rounded.